# Attending professional conferences using personal funds

Tags: conferences

My company won't be paying me to attend any industry conferences this year.

1. Is it worth spending a week of vacation time and more than a thousand dollars to attend one?
2. Is it a reasonable expectation on my boss' part that I share what I learn with my coworkers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am biased as I *do* spend my own time and money attending conferences when work doesn't. This often happens at the conferences I like to attend are in the wrong hemisphere to me.

But, this is a very personal decision, but there are a few questions I always ask myself before I pull out my credit card and book my flights:

- **Can you get some support from your boss?** They won't pay for you to go, but will they make you take vacation time? Often I am able to negotiate to attend on my own, and report back in return for not having to take leave. I've even had employers help organise side meetings that I wouldn't have otherwise attended. This way, everybody wins. This answers your second question, as if your boss *is* helping then there is a responsibility to give something back.
- **Is it relevant to work you want to do?** Conferences are networking events, and attending, especially on your own dime shows commitment to your boss and your peers who go. This means that people who see you there and know this will often look on this favourably.
- **Can you learn anything groundbreakingly new?** Conferences are great to learn things, not just during presentations but at dinners and side events are where I often see what will be on next years agenda. You really need to commit to seeing and sharing something new.
- **Will you make some new and influential connections?** These events are great ways to meet people beyond your usual circle of influence,. So attending on your own, there is a huge responsibility to put your name out there and meet people.
- **Is it a decent return on your investment?** If the trip costs $2000 to attend, can you foresee at least $2000 of increased salary in your future that you can attribute to this event?
- **Is it worth attending for personal reasons?** (ie. will you have fun?) I have a lot of peers who I *only* see at the specific conferences I attend, so often I am spending what would be vacation money attending. If I don't get a decent ROI is it worth spending my vacation money attending?
- **Are you presenting?** As HLGEM raised, an important way of getting exposure is presenting, at least in some fashion. Getting on a panel, presenting a paper or poster, or even attending meetings in some capacity is a great way to get professional exposure.

**If you can't say yes to *most* of these questions, then its probably not worth attending.**

Comment: I will also add that if you really go to make connections, it is probably worth it to start giving presentations.

Comment: Additionally, in some jurisdictions (like Australia) attending professional conferences on your own money is a tax-deductible expense.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it worth spending a week of vacation time and more than a thousand dollars to attend one?

You have to decide that for yourself, both before and after the fact.

You, not us, are the one who has to decide what they want to learn and get from the conference. And you, not us, are the one who has to make the determination as to what you learned and got from the conference and whether what you learned and got were worth the time and money you spend. @LegoStormtrooper, in his answer, pretty much shows that he has worked out how to max out on the benefits of attending a conference.

> Is it a reasonable expectation on my boss' part that I share what I learn with my coworkers?

You can try refusing to share what you have learned, and that will make for some interesting interactions interactions between you and your team and you and your boss - interactions that will put you in a bad light, and for which your boss may extract a price from you in terms of continuing work assignments, roles not to mention the upcoming salary/performance review.

You're probably better off using the knowledge gained as an edge in getting roles and assignments and in claiming credit for work performed, and sharing it in whatever way you see fit whenever requested. It's probably to early to speculate on whether this edge would help another employer, but this is is something to keep in the back pf the mind.

What you were asking is whether you're better off hoarding or sharing. The answer is a matter of personality and bias more than anything else. If you are a natural hoarder, you will find reasons to hoard and you will consciously or unconsciously downplay the consequences that come with hoarding. My bias is sharing,I share to get and I usually find that that no matter how much I share, I am getting back more than I am sharing and I will will consciously or unconsciously downplay whatever negative consequences come with sharing.

Sharing and looking for ways to profit from the sharing is probably the solution that capitalist economies have come up with and the middle ground that capitalist societies live with. Hoarding is like putting the money in the mattress. Money put in the mattress is money out of circulation and this money does not help either the owner of this money nor the economy. Whereas putting the money in the bank puts the money to work and benefits both the owner and the economy.

But there is a downside to putting the money in the bank,it's called risk: you could put the money to work and get nothing from it just as sharing the knowledge may get you nothing. Again, you have to do your own risk/benefit calculations and the answer that you come up with will usually very much fit your risk taking or risk adverse bias.

Answer (score 1):

1) Only you can answer that, since we don't know you, your field, which conference you're considering, etc. What do you think you'll learn, or what connections do you think you'll make, that will advance your career? Do you think that will be of more value to you than the cash and time you'll invest? If yes, go; if not, don't.

2) That's one of the ways you can use this to advance your career -- by demonstrating to the boss that you're trying to make your group and the company stronger. If you aren't going to do that, I'm not sure why you're considering going.

Comment: To be honest, if I were to sacrifice my holiday and my money to attend a conference, and the company refuses to support this in any way, then I'm doing this to make myself stronger, not the company or my group.

Comment: Making yourself stronger includes making yourself more valuable to your employer so you get promotions/raises/responsibility/etc. Part of that is showing that you are more valuable. Becoming stronger does you no good unless you use that strength, and unless you're planning to change jobs soon that's going to mean using it through your current employer. I've learned over the decades that standing on my dignity doesn't do anything but get muddy footprints all over it.